# JMS AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE when is it acknowledged?

Tags: java, jms, messaging

I have tried to google this, but have not been successful. If I am using `AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE`, and I have a consumer client written in Java, when is the message acknowledged? I am using a `MessageListener` which contains an `onMessage` method. Is the acknowledgement sent back to the server before `onMessage` or after `onMessage` completes or at some other point? Thanks in advance for any help anyone is able to provide!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Please check this [one](https://web.archive.org/web/20191101094431/http://www2.sys-con.com:80/itsg/virtualcd/Java/archives/0604/chappell/index.html) *(Wayback Machine link used as article went offline since 2020)*

With `AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE` mode the acknowledgment is always the last thing to happen implicitly after the `onMessage()` handler returns. The client receiving the messages can get finer-grained control over the delivery of guaranteed messages by specifying the `CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE` mode on the consuming session.

The use of `CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE` allows the application to control when the acknowledgment is sent. For example, an application can acknowledge a message - thereby relieving the JMS provider of its duty - and perform further processing of the data represented by the message. The key to this is the acknowledge() method on the Message object, as shown in Listing 1.

The `acknowledge()` method informs the JMS provider that the message has been successfully received by the consumer. This method throws an exception to the client if a provider failure occurs during the acknowledgment process. The provider failure results in the message being retained by the JMS server for redelivery.

Comment: What happens if an exception is thrown during the processing of `onMessage()`? Will the message be redelivered if the `AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE` is set?

Comment: @Geek - If exception is thrown in onReceive or in the JMSListener then the acknowledgment is not sent and will be redelivered

Comment: If receiving messages synchronously with AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE, the message is acknowledged when calling the consumer.receive method

Comment: @GameSalutes  - can you describe in detail how is the message redelivered and who delivers the message again and when does this redelivering happens?

Answer (score 15):

**CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE**
With this acknowledgment mode, the client acknowledges a consumed message by calling the message's acknowledge method.

```
Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
...
msg = (TextMessage) consumer.receive();
//acknowledge
msg.acknowledge();
```

**AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE**
With this acknowledgment mode, the session automatically acknowledges a client's receipt of a message either when the session has successfully returned from a call to receive or when the message listener the session has called to process the message successfully returns.

```
Session session = connection.createSession(false,Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
```

[source](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Session.html)
[Best example](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/jms/jms-client-example/)

Comment: Quite descriptive and helpful. Thanks!

Comment: "when the message listener the session has called to process the message successfully returns." sounds weird