# Resend JMS message if response is not received

Tags: java, servlets, jms, terracotta

I am trying to build a simple chat app using Java Servlets and JMS.

I have set up two channels(msg and ack).

msg to send the message and ack to receive the acknowledgement.

How do I send the message again if the acknowledgement is not received within a specified time?

Please ask if more details are required.

Comment: Who is sending the `ack`, the chat peer, or the JMS server? If server, acks are automatic is using `AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGMENT`.

Comment: I am using 'AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGMENT'. How do I make sure whether I got the ack for a message or not? Do I get a boolean value telling me that the server received the response? If yes, how and where do I access this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When sending a JMS message using `AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGMENT`, the message is auto-ack'ed by the server. If the server throws a JMSException back to the client, something went wrong and the message was either not received or persisted by the server; this is the signal to resend the message.

If no exception is thrown, you can assume the message was received by the server. You don't need a separate `ACK` channel for this; it's implied through JMS.

Additional Info 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11673930/791406